# Discord.py Userinfo command joined at and created at times

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to know how I can change my account created at and joined at times from the year/month/day format and flip it so it's day/month/year

```
@commands.cooldown(1,5,BucketType.channel)
async def userinfo(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
  if member == None:
    member = ctx.author
  try:
    roles = [role for role in member.roles[1:]]
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = discord.Color(0xff3400),
    title = f"{ctx.author}")
    embed.add_field(name="**•ID•**", value=f"{member.id}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Status•**", value=str(member.status).replace("dnd", "Do Not Disturb"), inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"**•Roles• ({len(ctx.author.roles) - 1})**", value='• '.join([role.mention for role in roles]), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Account Created At•**", value=f"{member.created_at.date()}".replace("-", "/"), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Joined Server At•**", value=f"{member.joined_at.date()}".replace("-", "/"), inline = True)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}", text = f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  except:
    roles = [role for role in member.roles[1:]]
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = discord.Color(0xff3400),
    title = f"{member}")
    embed.add_field(name="**•ID•**", value=f"{member.id}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Status•**", value=str(member.status).replace("dnd", "Do Not Disturb") , inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"**•Roles• (0)**", value="No roles", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Account Created At•**", value=f"{member.created_at.date()}".replace("-", "/"), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Joined Server At•**", value=f"{member.joined_at.date()}".replace("-", "/"), inline = True)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}", text = f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a date format variable first:

```
date_format = "%a, %d/%b/%Y"
```

%a --> Wed (day)

%d --> 14 (day)

%b --> Apr (month)

%Y --> 2021 (year)

Then simply put `strftime(date_format)` after `member.created_at`:

```
f"Account Creation: {member.created_at.strftime(datetime_format)}"
```

Output:

```
>> Account Creation: Wed, 14/Apr/2021
```

Comment: @Phoenix no problem, you can also customize the format codes from this website: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html. Simply CTRL + F and type in "Format Codes".